# Profile Posts Data From Facebook Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

Can I get posts data that are public published from Profile Accounts with Facebook Graph? Thus Not Page Accounts but Profile Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only get posts of user profiles if a user authorized your App with the `user_posts` permission. It does not matter if posts are public, you always need user authorization.

Comment: Okay thanks for your fast answer. Is this possible to scrape the data for this pages?

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook. there is no way. you must ask users for authorization to get access to their feed.